# Как установить новую библиотеку в Pythonista?

Tags: python

Хочу скачать библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI, но я работаю в Pythonista на iPad и не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно, ответу [тут](https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/2355/how-do-i-install-packages-from-pypi-into-pythonista-on-ios) можно поставить [StaSh - Shell for Pythonista](https://github.com/ywangd/stash) и тогда, в `StaSh` использовать `pip`.

[Установка `StaSh`](https://github.com/ywangd/stash#installation) (движок не пропускал ссылку на bit.ly, поэтому пришлось ее испортить, уберите пробел после `bit.`):

```
import requests as r; exec(r.get('https://bit. ly/get-stash').content)
```

После, в stash:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: Всё получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @user404455, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)